# How to make divs wrap *only* at their max-width, and not because its parent container is being overflown?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a `parent` container with a fixed size, and absolutely positioned `child` divs inside it. The position of the child divs have dynamic text content and a max-width and can move around freely, and extend outside of the `parent`, which is set to `overflow: hidden`. See the snippet at the bottom for illustration.

This works fine except for one small problem: If a child partially sticks outside the parent container to the right, the text inside of it will wrap, trying to stay inside of the parent container. I do explicitly not want this - if a child moves out of the parent, it should not change its wrapping or size because of it, it should just move out of view. The parent should simply act as a "window" of sorts through which the children are viewed.

I've tried different combinations of applying `white-space: nowrap` to the parent and/or children, none of which have worked for me so far. Is this just not possible?

This snippet demonstrates the problem:

```css
/* Relevant parent and child styles */

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 250px;
}


/* Individual positioning of child elements */

#fine {
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}

#wrapped {
  top: 90px;
  left: 400px;
}

#unwrapped {
  top: 330px;
  left: 170px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* The rest is only styles to make the example easier on the eye */

body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.child {
  padding: 12px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="fine" class="child">
    Text should be wrapped normally with the max-width of the child, like this
  </div>
  <div id="wrapped" class="child">
    This text will be wrapped much earlier though because it is running out of the parent container
  </div>
  <div id="unwrapped" class="child">
    "white-space: nowrap" only prevents *all* wrapping
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `left` to position the element but consider translate instead. The left property will restrict the width of your element.

```css
/* Relevant parent and child styles */

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 250px;
}


/* Individual positioning of child elements */

#fine {
  top: 30px;
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

#wrapped {
  top: 90px;
  transform: translateX(400px);
}

#unwrapped {
  top: 200px;
  left: 170px;
}
#extra {
  top: 300px;
  left: 170px;
}



/* The rest is only styles to make the example easier on the eye */

body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.child {
  padding: 12px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="fine" class="child">
    Text should be wrapped normally with the max-width of the child, like this
  </div>
  <div id="wrapped" class="child">
    This text will be wrapped much earlier though because it is running out of the parent container
  </div>
  <div id="unwrapped" class="child">
    "white-space: nowrap" only prevents *all* wrapping
  </div>
  
   <div id="extra" class="child">
    short text
  </div>
</div>
```

Or consider a big negative margin (at least equal to `max-width`) to negate the use of left:

```css
/* Relevant parent and child styles */

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin-right:-250px;
}


/* Individual positioning of child elements */

#fine {
  top: 30px;
  left:100px;
}

#wrapped {
  top: 90px;
  left: 400px;
}

#unwrapped {
  top: 200px;
  left: 170px;
}
#extra {
  top: 300px;
  left: 170px;
}


/* The rest is only styles to make the example easier on the eye */

body {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 24px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.child {
  padding: 12px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="fine" class="child">
    Text should be wrapped normally with the max-width of the child, like this
  </div>
  <div id="wrapped" class="child">
    This text will be wrapped much earlier though because it is running out of the parent container
  </div>
  <div id="unwrapped" class="child">
    "white-space: nowrap" only prevents *all* wrapping
  </div>
  
  <div id="extra" class="child">
    short text
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To understand how both tricks work you need to refer to [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) where you can find the formula to calculate the width of your element:

> The constraint that determines the used values for these elements is:
>
> `'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block`

You can then read the different case where some values are specified and other `auto`

Comment: Thank you, the trick with the margin works perfectly! Produces another issue in my specific case but I can fix that. Transform would have been an option but that is already being used for something else in my code and would be a hassle to combine both jobs into one.